# How to convert from System.EventArgs to Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechRecognition?

Tags: c#, winforms, speech-recognition

This are my part of the codes:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 this.RecognitionWithMicrophone(sender, e);
}

private async Task RecognitionWithMicrophone(object sender, SpeechRecognitionResultEventArgs e)
{
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)async delegate
   {...
```

This is the error code which I have received:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.EventArgs' to
>   'WebAppTeleBot.Form1.SpeechRecognitionResultEventArgs'    WebAppTeleBot   C:\Users\Piglet\Desktop\2018
>   FYP\TEST FOR
>   TELEBOT\ClientTelebot(test)\WebAppTeleBot\WebAppTeleBot\Form1.cs  347 Active

The error line I received is at the 3rd line: the parameter `e`. How to convert the parameter `e` to the `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechRecognition`?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you cannot do this conversion ever and I think you don't even have to. The EventArgs for a button click has nothing to do with speech recognition.

Why don't you just pass nulls?

```
this.RecognitionWithMicrophone(null, null);
```

Or create the SpeechRecognitionResultEventArgs with necessary parameters.